# How can I generate an array based on the grouped values of another array in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Lets say I have the following array:

```
`Z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]`
```

I want to generate  an array  that looks like this:

```
R = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], ..., [11,12,13,14]]
```

How can this be done with NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks
Z = np.arange(1,15,dtype=np.uint32)
R = stride_tricks.as_strided(Z,(11,4),(4,4))
print(R)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 2  3  4  5]
 [ 3  4  5  6]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 6  7  8  9]
 [ 7  8  9 10]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [10 11 12 13]
 [11 12 13 14]]
```

As [navneethc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7918173/navneethc) righly pointed out this function should be used with [caution.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)

Comment: The documentation for this function has an important note on its behaviour, so it's advisable to read it before using it. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html